# Problema para imprimir centralizado no C

Tags: c, c++, formatação

Estou com o seguinte problema, no meu código eu quero que o programa imprima de forma centralizada o número 1 depois da "palavra", e para centralizar estou utilizando o parâmetro `"%-20s \t"` para tentar centralizar o número após a palavra, porém em palavras com mais de um acento, a mesma não segue a tabulação.

Segue o código fonte:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<locale.h>

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    int i = 0;
    char nomes[3][15];
    strcpy(nomes[0], "palavra");
    strcpy(nomes[1], "palavrãozzz");
    strcpy(nomes[2], "palavrãozão");

    for(i = 0; i < 3 ; i++){
        printf("%-20s \t1\n", nomes[i]);
    }
}
```

A saída:

> ```
> [Running] cd "c:\Users\Pierre\Desktop\1\" && gcc *.c -o main && "c:\Users\Pierre\Desktop\1\"main
> palavra               1
> palavrãozzz           1
> palavrãozão           1
>
>
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 0.242 seconds
> ```

Gostaria que a saída fosse:

```
palavra                 1
palavrãozzz             1
palavrãozão             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A formatação do `printf()` foi feito para trabalhar com textos muitos simples, em ASCII. Na verdade todas funções básicas de C são para tarefas bem padronizadas, quando você sai um pouco da necessidade mínima programadores C usam bibliotecas de terceiros ou próprias para fazer a maioria das tarefas. Um [exemplo pode ser visto no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35427865/221800).

A formatação do `printf()` não funciona bem com acentos.

Então a solução é criar algo diferente para lidar bem com isso, ou fazer um algoritmo que lide com textos acentuados, ou pelo menos fazer a impressão manualmente caractere por caractere e não usar a formatação do `printf()`. Ou ainda, o que eu acho que para um exercício de algoritmo que é o que 99% das pessoas fazem em C e não importa os detalhes, não usar acentuação:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char nomes[3][15];
    strcpy(nomes[0], "palavra");
    strcpy(nomes[1], "palavraozzz");
    strcpy(nomes[2], "palavraozao");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3 ; i++) printf("%-20s\t1\n", nomes[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/c599I2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/FormatNoAccentc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/FormatNoAccent.c).